# jquery resize image

Tags: jquery, css

Hey guys, quick question, all I want to do is resize an image to fit inside a small container when I run this function. Right now, only a portion of the image is shown inside the div. If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate any advice.

```
$(this)
       .css({
           backgroundImage    : 'url(' + src + ')',   // set background image
           backgroundPosition : 'center center',      // position background image
           backgroundRepeat   : 'no-repeat'           // don't repeat image
       });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only very modern browsers (meaning Webkit) can scale background images. So I'd recommend inserting a new DOM element as the image and then changing it's height and width should scale it down. Than use CSS (things like position and z-index should help you) to position it where you need it.

Comment: Agreed. You should do this if you want a good browsing experience for all. You'll need to do some aspect ratio calculations if your images are going to be different sizes as well.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is css:

```
#container{
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    }
```

Jquery:

```
var url = "your_url";
$('#container').css("background-image", url);
```